# Reading byte array from JNI corrupts memory

Tags: java, android, camera, java-native-interface

I am getting a crash which seems to be caused by a memory corrupted error. After some research, I notice the memory writing maybe occurs at the following code. The context is I get video data from `Camera.PreviewCallback` interface, and call a native method `static native int pixel_push(long something, byte[] buf)`. So, could anyone help me to figure out what the error is?

---

java:

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    Log.e("zylthinking", "buffer_size = " + buffer_size + ", length = " + data.length);
    int n = mmapi.pixel_push(something, data);
    if (n == -1) {
        Looper looper = handler.getLooper();
        looper.quit();
    } else {
        camera.addCallbackBuffer(new byte[buffer_size]);
    }
}
```

jni:

```
jint length =  (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, pixel); 
(*env)->GetByteArrayRegion(env, pixel, 0, length, (jbyte *) mbuf->ptr[1]);
```

or:

```
jint length =  (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, pixel); 
jbyte* buf = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, pixel, NULL); 
memcpy(mbuf->ptr[1], buf, length); 
(*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, pixel, buf, 0);
```

will cause some code crash because of writing memory of otheres

however:

```
jint length =  (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, pixel); 
jbyte* buf = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, pixel, NULL); 
memset(mbuf->ptr[1], 0, length); 
(*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, pixel, buf, 0);
```

will be OK

another more, if I modify the java code to:

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    Log.e("zylthinking", "buffer_size = " + buffer_size + ", length = " + data.length);
    int n = mmapi.pixel_push(something, new byte[buffer_size]);
    if (n == -1) {
        Looper looper = handler.getLooper();
        looper.quit();
    } else {
        camera.addCallbackBuffer(new byte[buffer_size]);
    }
}
```

and everything is OK again.

And I now find another thing:
If I copy data to buf, the crash occurs again. If I comment that line, everything seems OK. 
It is totally mess me up.

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    byte[] buf = new byte[data.length];
    System.arraycopy(data, 0, buf, 0, data.length);

    int n = mmapi.pixel_push(something, buf);
    if (n == -1) {
        Looper looper = handler.getLooper();
        looper.quit();
    } else {
        camera.addCallbackBuffer(new byte[buffer_size]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that both `pixel` and `buf` are non-NULL? What do you get for `length` when the crash occurs?

Comment: Yes, the pixel and buf is absolutely none-NULL.

Comment: You should include the stracktrace for the crash in your question.

Comment: It crashes in x264.  And it looks now like the data fed to x264 causes x264 crash, because if I memset the data to zero before I feed it to x264, then nothing happens. However, I don't understand why x264 will crash for the data indeed is a normal picture,

Comment: Which [format](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html) does `getPreviewFormat` return, and what format is your x264 encoder expecting the input data to be in?

Comment: it is nv21, but I cheat x264 as nv12,  after the crash, I swapped the u,v to convert it to be the real nv12, but it still crashes. But if I memset all pixeles of y, u, v panels to be zero, then no crash happens again

Comment: Perhaps I have a similar problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64514315/android-jni-x264-encoder-encode-out-of-memory-error